# How to flip normals of a curve with object bevel?

Tags: modeling, normals

I'm working on this model:
[image: ant]
I did the antennae and legs using curves with an object bevel. As you can see the generated mesh has normals in the wrong direction. I tried fixing this by selecting all segments of the curve and switching their directions, but this doesn't help. Any idea on how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use an object to give a bevel to the curve you need to change the direction of the bevel object to flip the normals.

Select the Object > Edit Mode > Segments > Switch Direction

Comment: Thanks, that makes total sense. Don't know why but I was switching the direction of the base curve.